# Using RNCryptor to decrypt data throws "Decryption error: unknownHeader"

Tags: swift, objective-c, decode, encode, rncryptor

I have used RNCryptor in my objective-c project to encrypt and decrypt a plist data file. Now I am recreating the project in Swift. When I try to decrypt the plist data in swift project which was created in objective-c project, it always throw "Decryption error: unknownHeader". I am using the same app identifier so that I can access the same plist file which was stored in App's Document's directory. Could someone advise what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

Objective C - Encrypting and Saving to directory:

```
- (void)savePasswordlistItems {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:items forKey:@"MyKey"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
   
    NSError *error;
    NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                        withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                            password:MY_SECRET_KEY
                                               error:&error];
    [encryptedData writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    }
```

Objective C - Decrypting, decoding, adding to NSmutableArray:

```
- (void)loadPasswordlistItems {
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        
        NSError *error;
        NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:data
                                            withPassword:MY_SECRET_KEY
                                                   error:&error];

        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData: decryptedData];
        items = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"MyKey"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    }
    else
    {
        items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }
    
  
}
```

Swift - Decrypting, decoding and adding to NSMutableArray:

```
func loadPasswordlistItems() {
        let path = dataFilePath()
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                
                do {
                    let decryptedData = try RNCryptor.decrypt(data: data, withPassword: Constants.MY_SECRET_KEY)
                    let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: decryptedData)
                    items = (unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "MyKey") as! NSMutableArray)
                    unarchiver.finishDecoding()                    
                } catch {
                    // Handle decryption error
                    print("Decryption error: \(error)")
                }
            } catch {
                // Handle reading data from file error
                print("Error reading data from file: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            items = []
        }
    }
```

Swift - Encoding, Encrypting and writing to Directory (I haven't test this as I could not decrypt the existing plist file):

```
func savePasswordlistItems() {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
        archiver.encode(items, forKey: "MyKey")
        archiver.finishEncoding()
                
        let encryptedFile = RNCryptor.encrypt(data: data as Data, withPassword: Constants.MY_SECRET_KEY)
        do {
            try encryptedFile.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: dataFilePath()), options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unknown header indicates the first bytes of the cipher text are incorrect. Looking at your ObjC encryptor and Swift decryptor, they look fine. My suspicion is that the output of the ObjC encryptor is not actually what you're reading. I would dig into that ; making sure the output of one is exactly the input of the other, and that you're using the same version of RNCryptor in both cases (which it seems like you are; I suspect a reading or writing problem).

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for providing such an awesome library. Appreciate your assistance. It decrypts and decodes perfectly in obj-c version. So I am not sure what’s happening in swift version. Anything to do with “kRNCryptorAES256Settings” which used during encrypting in obj-c?

Comment: That shouldn't be it. The message is complaining that the very first byte isn't 0x03 (which is the "header" in question.) Here's the file format; it's very simple: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/04378bc27c604e97353badbead8c435698abe97a/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md

Comment: Somehow it works I add the name of the class used for NSCoding. 

Before encoding: NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Item", for: Item.self)
Before decoding: NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Item.self, forClassName: "Item")

Comment: That make it sound like the `unknownHeader` is coming from the `NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom:)` rather than from `RNCryptor.decrypt`. Is that possible?

Comment: I also believe that the error is coming from Unarchiver.